# How do I stop the camera preview without taking picture in Android

Tags: android, camera, preview

I have set up a FrameLayout to be the preview screen for my camera and it works great.

```
private void fireUpCamera() {
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();  // Create an instance of Camera
    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);// Create our Preview view.
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.quest_image);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

how do I release this preview and camera in my cancel button without taking the picture?

Comment: What do you mean by "release"? Remove it?

Comment: I want the frame to go blank again. calling fireUpCamera brings up the preview. My cancel button should stop the preview and camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the `mPreview` view from the `FrameLayout` named `preview` you could simply remove the view from the layout like this:

```
preview.removeView(mPreview);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following function to make sure you have released the camera on cancel. You will need to reinitialise it with your `fireUpCamera()` method if you want to use it again.

```
protected void closeCameraAndPreview() {    
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera .stopPreview();
        mCamera .setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        mCamera .release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
    preview.removeView(mPreview);
}
```

I implemented it this way so that the camera was properly released rather than just hidden from sight.